# How to restore Docker images after "Reset Factory Settings"?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I had a problem with launching Docker, and looks like `Reset Factory Setting` deletes data as well reseting Docker settings. Is there any way to retrieve my images?

I can see the following in my `trashcan: Docker (17656).app`.

Comment: trying to understand the issue: so you would like to store/save the docker images before factory reset or something goes wrong..is that all you need ?

Comment: It's actually the other way around, I did a factory reset, and lost all my images, is there a way to retrieve them?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?